# Phonegap : Scaling HTML5 canvas for smaller screens

Tags: android, html, cordova, canvas, fabricjs

This is a Phonegap android app that uses HTML5 canvas (preferably with fabricjs). One of the required functionality is that it can load image from gallery/take picture from camera and save the image after some preset edits. The input image/image taken from camera may be different in size depending on the device but the output image needs to be of fixed size (900x450 in this case) always. The app is supposed to support devices with both smaller and bigger screens. I can load the image to the canvas of preset size and export data url (after edits). But how do I get around using it on a smaller screen? I can display a smaller scaled down canvas and do manipulations there and do the actual stuff on a hidden canvas of the required size, but that would be very messy. Is there a better approach to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just “scaling” your canvas element by setting its width/height via CSS?

This should not affect the *actual* pixel size of the canvas element.